# What java classes are associated with these nutch commands?

Tags: java, solr, nutch

I have the following commands which I've batched together. It runs Nutch and sends the results to Solr. I have read that these match up to Java methods which I'd like to use to run programmatically.

Which Java classes do these match up to?

```
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls(text file containing list of urls)
bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments
export SEGMENT=crawl/segments/`ls -tr crawl/segments|tail -1`
bin/nutch fetch $SEGMENT -noParsing
bin/nutch parse $SEGMENT
bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $SEGMENT -filter -normalize
bin/nutch invertlinks crawl/linkdb -dir crawl/segments
bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8080/solr/ crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

Thanks

Comment: This repo may help you understand what's going on inside: https://github.com/yegor256/nutch-in-java

Answer (score 0):

See: [Nutch - Commandline Options](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/CommandLineOptions)

Click on the respective command for each of the commands you've listed and the destination page will outline which class is being used:

For example:

- nutch inject - [bin/nutch_inject](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch_inject)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [guide](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse). The class names are generally same with the command names. Look for the classes with **main** in them.